# Help me identify a book about the war between 2 vampire clans/families

Tags: story-identification, vampire

can anyone help me finding this book i remember reading in the mid-2000s (Book was probably written no earlier than 1990)?
Here's what i can remember clearly, other details might or might not be accurate so for now i chose not to list them:

---

- The book is part of a series about vampires fighting each other, I seem to recall vampires being part of clans or families, but they might just be small groups.
- The vampires have some special powers but they mainly fight using medieval weapons, i remember axes, whips and daggers mainly.
- The protagonist is recovering from some kind of sickness (maybe he was just turned into a vampire?) during the first half of the book (during this time he is weak and unable to concentrate before getting his "full powers" later).
- The finale of the book is a 2-part battle, the first part i remember the protagonist (or maybe one of his friends) getting pinned on the ground by another vampire, before a friend decapitates the other vampire with an axe.
- After this little skirmish is over the protagonist and his friends begin chasing the main antagonist, i dont remember why but the protagonists gets side-tracked and spends a chapter speaking with an old woman, a kind of witch who warns him about his future(?).
- In the final showdown the antagonist is hiding behind a line of trees to avoid getting hit by throwing daggers (maybe a friend of the protagonist is an ace at throwing daggers? i remember her trying to hit him with no success), the antagonist is holding the protagonist son hostage before killing him.

---

I think the book ends with the antagonist running away and the protagonist swaring revenge for his son
Anyone knows something similar? i tried googling and came across [The Vampire Chronicles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Vampire_Chronicles) and apart from the name 'Lestat de Lioncourt' which rings a bell i can't recognize any of the books from my memory, then again i could be remembering things completely wrong.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Maybe some of the tie-in books for [Vampire:  the Masquerade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vampire:_The_Masquerade) RPG.  I assume there are some.

Comment: @eshier The settings seems to be similar but i remember the book being part of a series of books, in the last page there was something like "To be continued in [next book title]" but of course i cant remember the title, it may have not been the first in the series either.
If it can help i remember the book being quite light, maybe 200ish pages

Comment: Apparently, there were 2 13-book series.  One set in [modern times](http://whitewolf.wikia.com/wiki/Clan_Novel_Saga) and one in [the 1200s](http://whitewolf.wikia.com/wiki/Dark_Ages_Clan_Novel_Saga).  Don't know anything about the novels, but when you put vampire with clan and say 2 sides battling, I immediately think the RPG.

Comment: @eshier Interesting, i'll have to read the summaries of these novels.
It does seem to be a step in the right direction though, thank you very much!